# How to View base64 string in a pdf or image in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pdf, base64

I have a base64 string and i want to view it in my reactjs website. I used  tag and  tag and both are working fine in development, but in production the file does not load.

i tried both and both work in development and are being rendered but in development when i upload my website to the server it does not load

Why is that?

Here is my code:

```
   //documentContent is my base64 string
 <embed src={`data:application/pdf;base64,${documentContent}`} /> 

 <object data={`data:application/pdf;base64,${documentContent}`} type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

Comment: @how would i view the document in an <a></a> tag?

Comment: @KJ that is a completely different topic, I want to view the pdf not download it, I already implemented the download pdf.

Comment: @KJ thank you for your comments, but i didn't understand anything, if you have a working example or code that would be very helpful. Thank you